# .GetChanges shows always null

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I am using an `sqladapter` in order to change database values directly from from a `datagridview`.

For this purpose I use the code below:

```
private void ok_Modify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //modify mod = new modify();
    //modify_gv.DataSource = mod.TabletoMod(tickerBox.Text, FundBox.Text);        
    connetionString = Properties.Settings.Default.TraFra;
    connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
    Sql = "select * from Approval where Ticker ='" + tickerBox.Text + "'";
    try {
        connection.Open();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, connection);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        connection.Close();
        modify_gv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void modify_gv_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    try {
        cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        changes = ds.GetChanges();
        if(changes != null)
            adapter.Update(changes);
        //   MessageBox.Show("Changes Done");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

However, each time I do a change in the `datagridview`, the variable "changes" is always null. Do you know why?

Comment: Are you calling `AcceptChanges` anywhere? This clears the change tracking on data sets.

Comment: I tried  cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                ds.AcceptChanges();
                changes = ds.Tables[0].GetChanges(); but changes is still null

Comment: No, I mean *don't* call `AcceptChanges` is this will cause `GetChanges` to return nothing.

Comment: Ha ok understood, no I don't call {AccepChanges}

Comment: There will also be no changes immediately after loading the data set.

Comment: Ok , what I want to do is to change the cell value in the datagridview and update it in the database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13787/discussion-between-francops-henri-and-adam-houldsworth)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may find that the DataGridView control does not write changes to the underlying datasource until you move off the "current" row - hence, while the CellValueChanged event fires, it hasn't written the changes to the bound DataRow.

If, for example, you were to handle the "RowChanged" event of your DataTable object, GetChanges would return the changed rows *(you could also observe that the event only fires when you leave the row being edited)*.

I'm sure that there is a way to force the DataGridView control to write changes down to the underlying DataRow, but I haven't tried it *(BeginEdit/EndEdit ?)*.

Answer (score 0):

call `ds.AcceptChanges()` before `ds.GetChanges()`